# How to make a function that takes in a std::string parameter that will return the amount of anything surrounded by whitespace

Tags: c++, string

I want to create a function that takes in a `std::string` parameter and returns an `int` of the amount of words in it. Like this:

```cpp
int countWords(std::string){
    // code...
    return amountOfWords;
}
```

Comment: Please don't make significant edits to your question after getting an answer, to avoid invalidating the answers and confusing future readers.

Comment: yeah i just wanted to make my questions easier to understand and also because i got a question ban since i didnt know how to properly ask stuff on here :)

Comment: Yep, I figured. Would be great to come up with wording that makes the question more clear, yet doesn't prevent the answer from making sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a function stub:

```
int stub(const std::string& s/*don't deep copy the string*/)
{
    return function_you_found_online(s.c_str());
}
```

The function `c_str()` returns a `const char*` to the first character in `s`.

Using function stubs to wrap third party resources also has the advantage that you can switch out the resources at a later date without impacting your codebase too much.

Comment: That, or better yet, take a `std::string_view`

Comment: @WBuck: Feel free to answer; I'd upvote that.

Comment: Or just pass `s.c_str()` directly into a `function_you_found_online`

Comment: @Zereges: I'd always rather stub them unless you take the view that you permanently absorb the function into your codebase.

Comment: @WBuck: If `function_you_found_online` expects a nul-terminated string, `std::string_view` won't help.

Comment: @Jarod42 I didn't think it sounded like he/she wanted to pass the `string` elsewhere. How I perceived the question was that they wanted to create a `function` that takes a `string` parameter so that they could then count the `words` of a `string` within that same function. I guess I was just confused by the question.